# Mongoose findOne is not working on numeric field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below is the basic user profile schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    const userprofileSchema = new Schema({
        name:{type:String},
        userId: { type: Number, required: true },
        userName: { type: String, require: true },
        avatarUrl: {type:String , default:'https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH5Lm.jpg'},
        bio:{type:String},
        url: String
    })

    module.exports = mongoose.model("userprofile",userprofileSchema);
```

below is the document stored in mongodb:

```
 {  
    "avatarUrl": "avatarurl",
    "_id": "5edd2dfc7c213e044cc2783b",
    "userId": "1000",
    "name": "Sandeep Patel",
    "userName": "cs-dev",
    "url": "portfolioUrl",
    "bio": "Work in progress!"
    }
```

Now when I do `userPofile.findOne({userName:"value"}}` it gives me result but if I do same on numeric field ie `userPofile.findOne({userId:value}}` result is null.
I have checked many times. Do I missing something?.

**Mongoose version :5.9.18**

**mongod version: 3.6.12 (MMAPv1)**

Comment: What are exact conditions and the document you expect to find?

Comment: `userPofile.findOne({userName:"cs-dev"}}` working whereas  `userPofile.findOne({userId:1000}}` does not

Comment: What is the document you expect to find? – D. SM 8 mins ago

Comment: It is stored as string your userId field

Comment: @chandan_kr_jha got it, buddy . Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried reproducing the same problem on my node.js application but the findOne works on Numeric fields as well.

From the mongoDB document that you have pasted in the question, it seems like your Number field is being stored as a string.

It should be like this :

```
    {  
    "avatarUrl": "avatarurl",
    "_id": "5edd2dfc7c213e044cc2783b",
    "userId": 1000, (Notice the lack of double quotes here)
    "name": "Sandeep Patel",
    "userName": "cs-dev",
    "url": "portfolioUrl",
    "bio": "Work in progress!"
    }
```

After this,

`userPofile.findOne({userId:1000}}` works

So you probably need to typecast your variable while you're inserting into the database.

Comment: thanks, buddy, actually profile was created already in DB and I made this silly mistake. I should have been created and tested a new profile myself. Thanks anyway